# Integer Enum and Unboxing

Tags: java

```
public class Document{
    private Integer status;

    // get()/set()
}
```

Then an enum:

```
public enum DocumentStatusEnum {

        ACTIVE_DOCUMENT(2060),CANCELLED_DOCUMENT(2061),DRAFT_DOCUMENT(2062),PROCESSED_DOCUMENT(2063);

        private final Integer value;

        private DocumentStatusEnum(Integer value){
            this.value = value;
        }
        public Integer getValue(){
            return value;
        }
    }
```

In a method I'm using the above method as below:

```
Document d = new Document();
d.setStatus(2063);
if (d.getStatus() == DocumentStatusEnum.PROCESSED_DOCUMENT.getValue()){
{
       // print true;
    }
    else{
       // print false;
    }
```

I get true here. Looks alright. In the same method, After couple of lines, I do this:

```
d.setStatus(2060)
if (d.getStatus() == DocumentStatusEnum.ACTIVE_DOCUMENT.getValue()){
   // print true
}
else{
   // print false

}
```

I get a false. I researched and found something about caching and boxing features in Java. I converted the enum definition as this:

```
public enum DocumentStatusEnum {

    ACTIVE_DOCUMENT(2060),CANCELLED_DOCUMENT(2061),DRAFT_DOCUMENT(2062),PROCESSED_DOCUMENT(2063);

    private final int value;

    private DocumentStatusEnum(int value){
        this.value = value;
    }
    public int getValue(){
        return value;
    }
}
```

Now, no issues. I get true in both cases.

Question is why this happening? I feel this behaviour is extremely unstable. It's a large application I'm dealing with and I'm using `Integer == Integer` comparison every where. Am I safe here?

Comment: There are clean rules for the boxing / unboxing behavior, but for me the behavior is not always clear. therefore I prohibit autoboxing in my projects (cab be set to be handled like a compiler error in eclipse).

Comment: Is `status` ever null? If not then consider changing it to `int`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Integer` extends `Object` and therefore `==` is defined as reference equality, not value equality.

When comparing `Integer` with `int`, the `Integer` will be unboxed to an `int`, and the two operands will be compared for value equality.  (Unless the `Integer` value is `null`, in which case `NullPointerException` will be thrown instead.)  But `Integer == Integer` is never safe.

That said, because by default the runtime pre-allocates `Integer` instances for small integers (-128 through 127, according to [the OpenJDK source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Integer.java#Integer.IntegerCache)), you can often get `Integer == Integer` to work for small values.  But that behavior does not hold for larger values, and it is never required to hold.  So you should never assume that two instances of `Integer` (or `String`, or any `Object`) will compare equal using `==`, unless you are explicitly looking for reference equality.

Comment: +1, the pre-allocated objects can lead to some very unusual results.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `int` instead of `Integer`, unless you need to handle null values.

There are indeed issues with comparing `Integer` objects.  For example, the following will evaluate to false:

```
boolean test = (new Integer(1) == new Integer(1));
System.out.println(test); // "false"
```

These are just objects like any other.  The `==` operator, when used with objects, only evaluates to true if they are the exact same Java object (as opposed to the `equals()` method, which can be overridden to compare the internals).